Excel VBA - Do something if cells in range start with specific string
I'm trying to bold all cells in my column A range if the cell value starts with 5 spaces. Currently this is what I'm trying; producing the error code:

Run-time error '13':
Type mismatch

    Sub Bold ()
    Set BoldRange = Sheets("Formatted Data").Range("A13:A100000")
        
        If BoldRange.Value Like "     *" Then
           BoldRange.Font.Bold = True
        End If
    End Sub

Note, the error is occurring on line If BoldRange.Value Like "     *" Then. Not too sure of what I'm doing wrong?

For this you have to iterate through the range cell-by-cell with a For....Next loop.

As suggested above, I've modified to use a For...Next loop.
Sub Bold ()
Dim rcell As Range, BoldRange As Range
Set BoldRange = Sheets("Formatted Data").Range("A13:A100000")

For Each rcell In BoldRange.Cells
    If rcell.Value Like "     *" Then rcell.Font.Bold = True
Next rcell
End Sub


Some tips to make your code is more efficient.

Only handle the range which has data
Loading data into an array and check its value
Apply font style all at once

Microsoft documentation:

Range.End property (Excel)


Application.Union method (Excel)

Sub Bold()
    Dim rcell As Range, dataRange As Range, BoldRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long, oSht As Worksheet
    Set oSht = Sheets("Formatted Data") ' modify as needed
    lastRow = oSht.Cells(oSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set dataRange = oSht.Range("A13:A" & lastRow)
    Dim arrData: arrData = dataRange.Value
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        If arrData(i, 1) Like "     *" Then
            If BoldRange Is Nothing Then
                Set BoldRange = oSht.Cells(i, 1)
            Else
                Set BoldRange = Application.Union(BoldRange, oSht.Cells(i, 1))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    If Not BoldRange Is Nothing Then
       BoldRange.Font.Bold = True
    End If
End Sub


If I try this in a new workbook it works great, however if I try it in my current workbook it bolds everything in column A. Any idea on why this may be happening?

Have you tested with same If condition and same data set? eg. If arrData(i, 1) Like "abc*" Then

Yes, both the same. However I don't know if you'll be able to pinpoint without my actual workbook, so I don't think I will open that can of worms! Your solution still works and it's likely something behind the scenes in my workbook causing the problem. Appreciate the help on this!

It's difficult to answer. You could debug the code step by step (press F8 in VBE to run the code) and check the value of arrData(i, 1).

What did you found? What's wrong with it?

Debugging the entire macro doesn't do anything until I reach the last line If Not BoldRange Is Nothing Then BoldRange.Font.Bold = True. Then it seems to bold my entire A column.

If BoldRange isn't assigned any value (Range object), then BoldRange.Font.Bold = True won't run. I've updated the last If clause. It's easier for debugging.
